# jQuery - getting the class of a dynamic div by clicking another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title suggests, I would like to get the class of a dynamic div by clicking on another div ("div.secondclass"). Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.secondclass").click(function () {
        firstclass=$('#firstid').attr('class');
        alert("the class of the 1st div is ="+firstclass);
    });
});
```

Comment: How are the two divs related to one another?

Comment: Uh, firstid is the id. If you didn't know it, you could get it with attr('id')

Comment: Is there a question that goes with this?

Comment: What exactly does not work? By doing `firstclass=$('#firstid').attr('class');` in _firstclass_ you should now have the class of your div. It should work fine. Make sure the div has a class set.

Comment: The code you have above should work fine so long as you know the ID of the first element you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/3PhPC/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.secondclass").click(function () {
        var aClass = $('#firstid')[0]
                          .className
                          .replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, " ")
                          .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")
                          .split(" ");
        alert("The div with the id firstid has got these classes: " + aClass.join(", "));
    });
});
```